# WebView JavaScript on Android <script> tag

Tags: android

I'm having some problems trying to load an HTML code on the webView,

```
private final String WEB_VIEW_HTML ="<html><head><script src=\"http://www.mywebsite.com/reporter.js\"></script></head><body onload=\"reporter = new MyWebsite.Reporter(Key);\"></body></html>";
```

and after doing a `aWebView.loadData(WEB_VIEW_HTML_PROD, "text/html", "UTF-8");`

And after that I need to call the "reporter" object, to do some pings etc.

Something like:

```
public void reportPageLoad()
{
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            aWebView.loadUrl("javascript:reporter.reportPageLoad()");
        }
    });
}
```

But When I'm trying to call the "reporter" it doesn't exist. Any Ideas?